# When should I release my array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, nsarray

I am parsing some JSON from the internet and then adding them to an array which is the datasource for my UITableView. I am not sure when I should be releasing my array?

**.h: items**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*  items;
```

**.m: connectionDidFinishLoading**

```
// fetch succeeded    
    NSString* json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:retrievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Check ST status
    int status =  [[[[json_string objectFromJSONString] valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"status"]intValue];
    //NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* messages = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]; 

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
            messages = [[[json_string objectFromJSONString] valueForKey:@"messages"] valueForKey:@"message"];

            for (NSDictionary *message in messages)
            {
                [items addObject:message];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: "When should I release my X?" - as soon as possible! ;)

Comment: Can you post more complete code? As written this wouldn't work (or compile)

Comment: Updated with more complete code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One, you might want to declare `items` as an instance of `NSMutableArray` if you intend to call `addObject:` on it.

Two, declare it as a property so that if you end up getting it multiple times the older value will be released when you do.

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And the correct point of releasing it would be `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't want to release it immediately if you:

- use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method for detail views and pass this data to them
- define custom UITableViewCell styles in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method
- use this data elsewhere

Best practice is declare an instance variable and synthesize it in .m, use in appropriate operations and release in dealloc method.

One possible release point that you could use is where you refresh your data that shown on table.

### Example:

I get dictionaries in an array from an API in my app and use something like that.

#### MyTableViewController.h

```
@interface MyTableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;

@end
```

#### MyTableViewController.m

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

@synthesize items;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [items release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FilesCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"filetype_%@.png", [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"]]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        MyDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        detailViewController.item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];
        detailViewController = nil;
    }
}

- (void)getItems
{
    [items release];
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Do some requests here

    for (NSDictionary *dict in results)
    {
        [items insertObject:dict atIndex:0];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self stopLoading];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Releasing at wrong places some time lead to memory leaks, before allocation itself u can have a condition like if() { [...release]}.Not tested but this kind of release avoid leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common is to have the items variable as an attribute of your class, once you will probably need it to use in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

So, having it as an attribute variable you can release it on the `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your array `item` will be used by `UITableView` to  show data.

First declare it as instance variable in your .h class.

**.h class**

```
@interface MyClass 
{
  MSMutableArray* items;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) MSMutableArray* items;

@end
```

In your **.m** class.

```
@synthesis iMyArray;
```

And you code for filling the array should be

```
NSMutabelArray* itemsTemp = [[NSMutabelArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

messages = [[[json_string objectFromJSONString] valueForKey:@"messages"] valueForKey:@"message"];
[json_string release];

for (NSDictionary *message in messages) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[message valueForKey:@"body"]);
    [itemsTemp addObject:message];
}


self.items= itemsTemp;

[itemsTemp release];
itemsTemp = nil;

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Now in `dealloc` release your array instance.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
   if(items )
   {
    [items release];
    items = nil ;
   }
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Did you try using my answer ?

Comment: you don't need the if statement in dealloc

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is make it property in .h class, since you have declared it as property: remember one thing always alloc a property by using self.

your statement `items=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

is wrong.(use self) also since your property is `retain` type the using alloc on it increase retain count.that gives you a leak.

so use in this way in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.items=tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

then release your items array in `dealloc` and set it nil in `viewDidUnload`

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.items=nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.items release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Hope now you can understand how you should use this.

Comment: I would add you shouldn't release with the setter, but the ivar directly.
`- (void)dealloc {
    [items release];
    [super dealloc];
}`

Comment: Actually, by not using the `retain` setter, assigning the ivar directly to an alloc/init is perfectly fine. In either case, there's a +1 retain count, and you get the added benefit of not having to dump another object into a burgeoning autoreleasepool. Also, Holger makes a good point. It's mostly tradition and style, but no point in breaking something that works.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [documentation of UITableView reloadData method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData):

*"[...] For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible"*

That means yo should not release the items array as long as the table is being used, i.e. you have to declare the array as a property.

First because if you scroll the view, you will still need the `items` information to display the rows below or above.

And second, because by being a property you ensure that a previous value is going to be released if you happen to assign a new value to `items`.

Finally, the common place to release a property is in the `dealloc` method and depending on your implementation in `viewDidUnload` method.